# ParseCancellationException when using ANTLR4 `parser.file_input()` for Python files

Tags: python, java, antlr, antlr4, parse-tree

I am writing Java code using ANTLR4 to parse Python files. The lexer and parser I use are `Python3Lexer.g4` and `Python3Parser.g4` from `antlr/grammars-v4` Github. The java parsing code works fine most of the time, but sometimes I get the following error.

```
line 431:1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
Parser Exception: org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException
org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy.recover(BailErrorStrategy.java:51)
        at Python3Parser.simple_stmt(Python3Parser.java:1667)
        at Python3Parser.stmt(Python3Parser.java:1567)
        at Python3Parser.file_input(Python3Parser.java:348)
        at ConvertPython.serializeFile(ConvertPython.java:89)
```

Here is part of the ConvertPython.java:

```java
      Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromFileName(f));
      CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      vocab = lexer.getVocabulary();

      Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(tokens);
      ParserRuleContext t = parser.file_input(); // the exception line
```

Here is one failing Python:

```py
...
SYBYL2SYMB = {
    "Mo": "Mo",
    "Sn": "Sn",
}
```

When I tested it, I found this dict cannot be the last line of the Python file. If there is a new line after it, there is no exception.

Besides, I found there would be `line 231:7 no viable alternative at input 'resultmatrix_' Parser Exception: org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException` for Python code `print resultmatrix_`. I think it's because this code is Python2 but the ANTLR grammar I'm using is for Python3.

PS, I'm new to ANTLR. Please tell me what I should post for your understanding. Thank you a lot!

Comment: *"tell me what I should post"* An example of a failing Python source?

Comment: @Olivier An example is added.

Comment: If it's Python2, you might want to just go back to the "auto switching" version of the python grammar (grammars-v4/python/python/). I updated that grammar yesterday to now be tested and it works fine, even on your example with or without the end of line characters at the closing '}'. There may be a problem with the python/python3 grammar--it should probably take a "naked" (i.e., no trailing end of line characters) closing brace. The only way to know is to check the test against python3 and see what it does. While the grammar is "scraped" from the "spec", the grammar may be wrong.

Comment: @kaby76 Got it. Hope the python/python3 grammar can be improved later. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar expects a `NEWLINE` at the end of the "simple statement".

This works:

```java
String input = "SYBYL2SYMB = {\n" +
    "    \"Mo\": \"Mo\",\n" +
    "    \"Sn\": \"Sn\",\n" +
    "}\n";

Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(input));
Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

parser.file_input();
```

Comment: Adding "\n" to the end of every input string is a compromise and practical way to avoid this ParseCancellationException. Thanks!